# how add carosel in scrollview kivy

Tags: scrollview, carousel, kivy

i try to write some program i need to use caruosel in scrollview to make slider which go right and left in page which go top and down
not complex program just like this picture

[image]

i try to this but carousel not working and try to do it by two scrollview in scrollview but this plane too not working
this is my .kv code

```
<page1>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint:1,1
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            size_hint_y:None
            height: self.minimum_height
            Carousel:
                size_hint_y:None
                Button:
                    text: 'Slide one'
                Button:
                    text: 'Slide two'
```

and try this:

```
<page1>:
    ScrollView:
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y:1.5
            ScrollView:
                FloatLayout:
                    size_hint_x:1.5
```

how can make something like picture?
thank u for every answer

Comment: I've been trying for a while and it seems something is wrong with this adding carousel to scrollview. maybe you should open an issue on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do that by this code but slider is very hard to move :)

```
 <page1>:
        ScrollView:
            size_hint:1,1
            GridLayout:
                cols:1
                spacing:5
                size_hint_y:None
                height: self.minimum_height
                FloatLayout:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:200
                    Carousel:
                        size_hint_y:None
                        loop:True
                        direction:'right'
                        Button:
                            text: 'Slide one'
                        Button:
                            text: 'Slide two'
                        Button:
                            text: 'Slide three
```

'